# Mostrar imágenes desde una carpeta fuera del proyecto en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Quiero mostrar imágenes de productos pero estas se encuentran en una carpeta fuera de mi proyecto ej. C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Productos y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo ya que solo las he podido mostrar desde una carpeta del mismo proyecto pero  son demasiadas imágenes para pasarlas todas allí, trabajo en laravel 5.5

Intente esto pero no funcionó

```
<img src="{{('file:\\\C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Productos\\'.$articulo->IDENTIFICACION.'.JPG')}}"
```

Comment: no podras hacerlo. la imagen deberia estar dentro del proyecto, cual seria la razon de tenerlos fuera de la carpeta publica?¿ conoces algo de tecnologia web? es tu primera vez que haces algo asi.

Comment: con linux se podría, sin embargo creo que tu proyecto es más escolar y usas windows, entonces no se puede

Comment: Entiendo, gracias.